# JQuery prevendDefault [disable a link] within a list but not those in a child list

Tags: jquery, parent-child, children, preventdefault

I've got a link I want to disable. Problem is it's in an li that has a sublist so it also disables those links. The HTML looks basically like this:

```
<div id="main">
<ul class="index"><li class="firstLI"><a href="some other URL"></a></li>

<li class="secondLI"><a href="disableMe">Disable this Link</a>
   <ul>
        <li><a href="dontDisableMe">Don't Disable Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="dontDisableMe">Don't Disable Me</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li>third</li></ul>
</div>
```

I want to disable the 'a' within the 'li' class secondLI but not all of the accompanying UL's children.

I've tried:

```
function preventDefault(e) {
        e.preventDefault()};

    $("#main li:nth-child(2) a").bind("click", preventDefault);

    $(".secondLI").unbind("click", prevenDefault);
```

and

```
$("#main li:nth-child(2) a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do other stuff when a click happens
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`>` selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) that selects only the direct children.

```
$("#main li:nth-child(4) > a").click(function(e) { ...
```

Alternatively, if there's only one link use the [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).

```
$("#main li:nth-child(4) a:first").click(function(e) { ...
```

Or even better, give the link a class or an id if you can and select it directly.

Comment: Excellent! I used the first way (with the > selector) and that did it. I tried the second as well and it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Click events [bubble](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html): first the click handler of the li element is fired (if there is one), then the click handler of the parent, then that of the parent of the parent and so on. Any handler in this chain can cancel the default action. So if you have an event handler in the `li li` without `preventDefault` (or no event handler at all), and an event handler on the parent `li` with `preventDefault`, then the default action will be prevented.

Two simple ways around this:

- in the event handler of the outer `li`, check the target of the click (`e.target`) and only invoke `preventDefault` if it is not inside the child `ul`;
- in the event handler of the inner `li`, cancel bubbling (`e.stopPropagation`); that way, the event handler of the parent `li` won't be invoked at all.

Comment: Or if your event handler is only intended to handle clicks on the links, you could put them directly on the `a` tags, those are not nested.